# Null pointer exception in method called inside OnResume()

Tags: java, android

A little background: 
In my app when Wi-Fi is disconnected, I show an alertDialog with negative button to dismiss the dialog.I intentionally turn the Wi-Fi off which triggers the alertDialog to be displayed. I exit the app and launch again, I still see the alertDialog. Then I turn the Wi-Fi on and soon as the network connects if I dismiss the alertDialog everything goes fine but if I don't dismiss the alertDialog I get a null pointer exception. I do call a method in onResume() which updates the view.

```
protected void onResume() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onResume()");
        super.onResume();
        mIsSaveStateCalled = false;
        updateView();
        }
```

My updateView()

```
private synchronized void updateView() {
if (error) {

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DeviceActivity.this).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_warning)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.preference_title))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.preference_device_error_message, (mTestDevice == null) ? "device" : mTestDevice.getDisplayName()));
                dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int whichButton) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                final EditTextPreference editPreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("device_name");
                editPreference.setSummary();
                editPreference.setText();
 }
```

I display the alertDialog() among other things like editTextPreference etc...

As I mentioned above, the app crashes with null pointer exception if I don't dismiss the alertDialog and the stack trace points to the line right after the else statement above i.e. editPreference.setSummary(); this is line 248

I also see logcat printing updateView() is null.

Any help is appreciated.

stacktrace

```
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at com.test.android.DeviceActivity$3.run(DeviceActivity.java:248)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
07-17 22:25:20.690: E/AndroidRuntime(30125):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show the Stacktrace or logcat

Comment: I guess, there is something wrong on line  final EditTextPreference editPreference = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("device_name");

Comment: put this two lines of code editPreference.setSummary(); & editPreference.setText(); inside if block like if (editPreference!=null){editPreference.setSummary(); editPreference.setText();}. Issue is with editPreference is not getting initialized.

Comment: I have already tried it, This just pushes the NPE to the final PreferenceScreen restartPreference = (PreferenceScreen)findPreference("restart_this_device");
     restartPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){}  which follows the editTextPreference and if I add an if block here it just keeps pushing the npe further

Comment: then the `restartPreference` is also null. Maybe you should check, whether they even exist.